# Create json object in jsp page and process in same page's javascript

Tags: ajax, json, jsp

This is my `topranks.jsp` page codes:

```
<%
         JSONArray objarr = new JSONArray();
         if(courseid !=null && semName !=null && request.getParameter("year") !=null ){
                 ResultSet rsdiagram = new course().diagramResult_in_course(request.getParameter("year").toString(), semName, courseid);

                 if(rsdiagram !=null){
                     while(rsdiagram.next()){
                             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                             // Retrieve by column name
                             float grade = rsdiagram.getInt("grade");
                             String name = rsdiagram.getString("name");

                             obj.put("name", name);
                             obj.put("id", grade);
                             objarr.add(obj);
                     }
                     response.setContentType("application/json");
                     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

                     PrintWriter out1 = response.getWriter();
                     out1.print(objarr);
                     out1.flush();
                  }
          }
```

And this is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#show').click(function() {
    var urll=window.location.search;

    $.ajax({

        url : "topranks.jsp"+  urll,
        type : "get",

        success : function(info) {// in this function how I can access to json data in jsp page
            //alert(info.name);
            console.log(info);
            for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                alert(i + ":  " + info[i].name + "  " + info[i].id);
            }
     });
  });
});
```

In my `topranks.jsp` page I have a button when I click on that, my ajax code called and in the js code, I get json data from same page. How I can handle this problem?

Comment: why don't you make a separate JSP page that generates the JSON you want, make it dedicated for this, it should have no HTML tags, just <% %> jsp tag and code to generate JSON, though the best sol is to make a servlet or web-service to handle this task.

Comment: what you are getting currently when you do console.log(info);?

Comment: Entire page's html code!

Comment: @Farshid thats why i told you to create a separate jsp page WITHOUT html tags, or a servlet/web-service.